# Calculating R^2: two different results depending on method

Tags: regression, matlab, model, r-squared, trend

So I've fitted a linear trend to my data and calculated R^2 in two different ways (in Matlab), one is using `corrcoef` and the other is "by hand". These return different results and both seem to make sense, so I'm not sure why that is. My methods are as follows, with `x` being the number of years and `y` my values:

```
(1)
rsq1 = corrcoef(x, y);

(2)
%// fitting the model
p = polyfit(x,y,1);
yfit = polyval(p,x);

%// calculating R^2
yresid = y - yfit;
SSresid = sum(yresid.^2);
SStotal = (length(y)-1) * var(y);
rsq2 = 1 - SSresid/SStotal;
```

Since I'm very new to this I can't seem to figure out why `rsq1` and `rsq2` are different. I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious... does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: is `rsq1^2` equal to `rsq2`?

Comment: indeed it is! I guess I could've thought of that. thanks! so rsq1 is the one to use? or does rsq1^2 also have an application?

Comment: Just to note that `polyfit` requires 3 inputs so we cannot tell what kind of model you fitted; the order might be also off.

Comment: @usεr11852 right, I now added that (1st degree)

Comment: Thanks. In this case I think @Alex's answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The r-squared you get out of linear regression is equal to the square of the pearson correlation coefficient, which you have calculated as `rsq1`. So, both `rsq1` and `rsq1^2` have meaning, the former is the Pearson correlation, the second is the R-squared value you would obtain by linearly regressing `y` against `x`, which in your example is `rsq2`.

Comment: +1 because it is the correct answer and it took a bit of luck given that the initial problem formulation was somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @Alex I have one follow up question: so if I have two variables, e.g. temperature and plant growth, I could calculate the correlation coefficient which tells me how they are correlated. But when I have e.g. plant growth over **time**, and I fit a linear trend to it, maybe I'll rather use R^2, because it can tell me how well the trend fits the data. Would you say this makes sense?

Comment: I think that would qualify as a separate question, for which 'canonical' answers could be found here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83347/relationship-between-r2-and-correlation-coefficient. These answers all seem very math heavy so I will give my take on it: The correlation coefficient is used as a measure of how strong the linear relationship between the two variables are...

Comment: ... R-squared on the other hand compares two models for your observed `y`. The first model returns the following: given x, guess the mean of y as the value for observed y. The second model uses the line of best fit: given x, guess the y value of this line as the value for the observed y. R-squared quantifies how much better the second guess is when compared to the first guess.

Comment: so to answer your question: "how well does the linear trend fit the data (observed y)", you should use R-squared.

Comment: @Alex Thank you that makes sense; and I'll have a look into it!