# How is this simplified pearson coefficient derived?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, pearson-r

I came across a variation of the Pearson coefficient as seen here:

$$r=\left[1-\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{ti}-x_{pi})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n x^2_{ti}}\right)\right]^{1/2}\,,$$

where $x_{ti}$ is a target value and $x_{pi}$ is a predicted value.

I've seen the various forms of the r coefficient on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient), but can't figure out how you would get to this form. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: If $x_t$ has mean zero, the formula you've posted is the root of the $R^2$ stat, which is equal to the pearson correlation coefficient (see eg here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83347/relationship-between-r2-and-correlation-coefficient).

Comment: The formula is correct only for non-negative $r.$