# Graphical proof of variance decomposition for linear regression

Tags: regression, variance, variance-decomposition

Suppose we aim to predict $Y$ from $X$ using the linear regression model $Y = mX + b$.  There is a standard variance decomposition:

$$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{Var}[\widehat{Y}] + \operatorname{Var}[R],$$

where $\widehat{Y}=mX+b$ is the model's prediction at $X$ and $R=Y-\widehat{Y}$ is the residual.  Thus, the variance of the $Y$'s is equal to the sum of the variance of the predictions and the variance of the residuals.

I can derive this algebraically.  But is there a simple graphical proof?  Or some other way to see why this is true, in a way that doesn't require much in the way of formulas or algebraic derivations?

Comment: In subject space, Prediction and residuals are perpendicular vectors https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/124892/3277 with variances being their squared lengths. Therefore, according to pythagorean theorem.....

Comment: @ttnphns, interesting!  How can we see that they are perpendicular?  In other words, why are they guaranteed to be perpendicular?

Answer (score 1):

How about simply:

[image]

$Var[Y] = Var[red] + Var[blue]$

Code:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10, x)
plot(x, y, pch=19, col="blue", bty="n")
m <- lm(y ~ x)
abline(m, col="red")
ypred <- predict(m, newdata=data.frame(x=x))
segments(x, ypred, x, y, col="blue")
```

Comment: Yes, that is a good picture illustrating what that equation is saying.  But I'm asking for something to help explain why the equation is true.  Why should it be true that Var[y] = Var[red] + Var[blue]?  I'm not seeing how to get that from the picture.  Did you have some thoughts on that?  Apologies if my question was confusing/unclear.

Comment: Well, I'd say that the figure shows that there is some "red" variance which is what our model explains, but to get to the real y values we need to add the "blue" variance. Maybe a better question would be: how to show graphically why (given certain assumptions) is the sum of variances equal to the variance of the sum?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am asking.

Comment: OK, so maybe you should ask another question, without referring to linear regression.

Comment: This question is specific to linear regression, so it can't be asked without that context. It is not true in general that $\text{Var}[U+V]=\text{Var}[U]+\text{Var}[V]$; it happens to be true in this case, for the specific random variables mentioned in the question, due to some specifics about how those random variables are related, but the question is why -- the question can't be separated from the context.

Comment: It is always true if $Cov(U, V) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, I know.  If you like, you can think of my question as asking why $\text{Cov}(\widehat{Y},R)$ is equal to 0 for the quantities $\widehat{Y},R$ defined in my question.  It is true, but why?  In particular, I'm asking for an intuitive explanation/proof, e.g., with a picture; but not with detailed algebraic derivations.  (I am getting the impression that we might be miscommunicating somehow, as it feels to me like you are mentioning things that I already know but that don't answer the question...  Perhaps I have done a poor job of articulating my question?)

Comment: Y = PY + (I-P)Y, where PY is predicted values, (I-P)Y residuals and P and (I-P) projection matrices. Once you understand how these matrices works you understand why predicted values and residuals are orthogonal - zero covariance - and a graphical illustration of how the matrices work should answer the question. Maybe this is a place to start https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/projections.html