# $R^2$ of regression of unity on $X$ (i.e. $Y$ is a vector of ones)

Tags: regression, least-squares, goodness-of-fit

Assume we have a vector of ones and some (one or more) variables $X$, and we run a linear regression of unity on $X$ (i.e. if we only assume one RHS variable, the implied scatter plot would be a flat horizontal line). My questions are:

1. What would be intuitively the purpose of such a regression?
2. Given that $R^2 (= 1-RSS/TSS = MSS/TSS)$, is the proportion of the dependent variable explained by the model, and since in this setup $TSS=0$, I expected that statistical software would not return the $R^2$ figure in such a regression. However, they do (see *). I have identified two different conventions statistical packages use for calculating $R^2$, in this special regression case. The difference is on how they calculate $TSS$:

   - $TSS = T$ (where $T =$ # of obs)
   - $TSS = 2RSS$ (since $MSS=RSS$, due to $y_i = \bar y$)

The 2nd question is what is the rationale behind each of the two conventions for calculating $R^2$?

*For instance, for a regression of unity on a single $X$ without an intercept, $R^2$ in Stata (command: regress) and Excel (LINEST) is 0.83, while in MATLAB (fitlm) is 0.5. These figures imply that Stata and MS Excel use the first $TSS$ convention, while MATLAB uses the second approach.

Comment: To what software do you refer and what value of $R^2$ does it return?

Comment: @whuber using Stata I get R-squared 0.8330 and Adj R-squared 0.8323. In MATLAB, with the same set of two variables (unity and a single $X$), I get 0.5 for both R-squared and Adj R-squared.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that such a regression is completely meaningless. See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126363/r2-of-linear-regression-with-no-variation-in-the-response-variable) for a great discussion of it. Basically, since $y$ is always the same value, you don't observe any variation in it, and so intuitively you will always find that the intercept is equal to $y$, and all the other $\beta = 0$. Basically, you conclude that changing $x$ has no effect on $y$. But this is a special case of that, which can happen when $y$ is just independent of $x$, as any variable you used instead of $x$ would yield the exact same result. Furthermore, as the answers in that question reveal, there's really no concept of $R$ or $R^2$ in this case.

Now as to why you may observe an $R^2$ using statistical software, this is most likely because such software numerically solves for regressions, and so you won't exactly get that $\beta = 0$, but rather that $\beta \approx 0$. In particular, using using the example of R's code, the [documentation for lm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/source) calculates R squared as 
$$R^2 = \frac{mss}{mss+rss}$$
where $mss = \sum_i(y_{i,fit} - \bar{y})^2$ and $rss = \sum_i(y_{i,fit} - y_i)^2$.
But in your example, both of these values are incredibly small (due to approximation) but non-zero and equal as $y = \bar{y}$, and so you have $mss = rss$ and so
$$R^2 = \frac{mss}{mss+rss} = 1/2 =.5$$
which is what I suspect many software might conclude.

So what's going on? Well in this case, R used the equality that $mss + rss = tot$, where $tot = \sum_i ((y_i - \bar{y})^2)$. So instead of calculating $tot$ to get the denominator of $R^2$, it instead used $mss + rss$, but in this case, $tot = 0$ but $mss + rss \neq 0$ due to approximation issues, but again fundamentally the concept of $R^2$ doesn't exist here, and so these equations fail to hold.

See below for an example reproducing the problem in R:

```
n = 1000
y = rep(1,n)
x = rnorm(n, mean = 100)

reg = lm(y~x)

r = reg$residuals
f = reg$fitted.values

mss = sum((f - mean(f))^2)
rss <- sum(r^2)

rsq = mss/(mss+rss)
[1] 0.499924
```

### UPDATE (after comments)

Let's now consider forcing no intercept, and asked in the comments of this post by OP. First, the intuitive purpose of this regression would be to recover identified information of $X$ without needing $Y$, and so the regression would be 'useless' in that sense: all the information would be contained in the data $X$ without $Y$. This should make sense: the observed $Y$ is a constant. On a more fundamental sense, let's look at the model you're considering. Sticking to the simple linear regression case, you're saying that the underlying model is $y = f(x) = \beta x + \epsilon$, and so $E[y|x=0] = 0$, but you told me $E[y|x = 0] = y = 1$ as $y$ is a constant, so your model is already mis-specified.

Anyway, in the simple linear regression case, we have that without intercept, $y = \beta x$ and 
$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\bar{xy}}{\bar{x^2}} = \frac{\bar{x}}{\bar{x^2}}$$

where the last equality follows because $y = 1$ for all observations. You also asked that $\bar{x} = 0$, so $\hat{\beta} = 0$ in your example regardless, unless $\bar{x^2} = 0$, in which case it's undefined. So you know exactly what $\hat{\beta}$ is, and what it's identifying, and so the interpretation of a regression is equivalent to just studying $X$ on it's own. As for why various statistical software gives various $R^2$, I'd check documentation and go from there knowing what you identify.

I'd also be remiss not to link [this post on the pitfalls of $R^2$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous).. at least when I first learned about $R^{2}$, I certainly gave it way more attention than I should have, thinking it's somehow the 'ideal' measure of a regression.

Comment: In your answer, and the post you suggested, both assume that there is an intercept. In that case, not only $TSS$, but also $RSS$ is 0 (since for $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X +e$, we'll have $\hat\beta_0=1$ and $\hat\beta_1=0$). If we consider a model without an intercept, then even though $TSS$ is still 0, $RSS$ is not (since for $Y=\beta_1X +e$, the $\hat\beta_1 \neq 0$). So, the model with intercept indeed fits the data perfectly (hence $RSS=0$), but the model without the intercept, does not. The only commonality I see between the two is that in both cases, $TSS=0$, hence the variance of $Y$ is 0.

Comment: So, in the case with the intercept, indeed the regression might be meaningless. However, I am not convinced that the same is true for the model without the intercept. This latter case of the model without an intercept, and when $R^2$ is calculated using the convention of $TSS=T$, is used as a test statistic (defined as $T*R^2$) by Giacomini-White (2006) in evaluating relative accuracy of competing forecasting models. Hence my question for the meaningfulness of the regression.

Comment: You pointed out that $RSS=MSS$. Which implies that $TSS=2RSS$. Therefore, that justifies the rationale behind MATLAB’s computation of $R^2$. However, what is the rationale for computing $R^2$ by setting $TSS=T$ (such as in Stata and Excel)?

Comment: @CKara I updated my post.

Comment: I have already updated the post to include the two different ways that statistical packages calculate $R^2$. In the case of Stata they set $TSS=T$. In MATLAB they do what you have described above i.e. use the fact that $RSS=MSS$, implying that $TSS=2RSS$. The question remaining to be answered is what is the logic behind setting $RSS=T$, and calculating the goodness of fit as $R^2=1-RSS/T=1-\bar e$?

Comment: I am dropping the assumption that the sample mean is around zero. I think it does not serve any purpose, and it is confusing. I didn't even assume it deliberately. Thank you for all the extremely helpful comments and post. I believe we are close, but something is missing, and I think the answer is hidden into why some software use the above-mentioned convention of $RRS=T$ in calculating $R^2$.

Comment: @CKara will look at this during my break, but could you provide a link and quote indicating that whichever software literally take $RSS$ to equal the number of observations?

Comment: Here is the Stata output (see 2nd table, 3rd row 1st column): 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AFakRFoPrqEfvBoL5VSYB0b27xpNOywJ