# Does $Cov(X,Y)=0$ imply that the sample covariance between realizations of $X$ and $Y$ is always zero?

Tags: covariance

For instance, in linear regression, we have that

$$
Cov(e,\hat Y) = 0
$$

That is, the residuals and fitted values are uncorrelated.

Is this always true in any sample realization of residuals and fitted values? I think the answer is yes, but I'm having some difficulty intuitively seeing why the population property carries over to every sample.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Regarding the title question, note that $P(\hat \theta = \theta) = 0 $ given that $\theta \in (a,b)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You can try first. Generate random number from standard normal, calculate the sample mean, to see if you can get sample mean = 0. repeat many times. When I talk with non-statistical researchers, I tell them the point estimate is 100% wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> Does $Cov(X,Y)=0$ imply that the sample covariance between realizations of $X$ and $Y$ is always zero?

**Certainly not!**  In fact, if you were to generate *only two* realisations of the pair of variables then you would almost certainly get perfect sample correlation!

To see this, consider two data points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ with $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $y_1 \neq y_2$.  It can easily be shown that the sample correlation of this data has a magnitude of one!  That is, they have a perfect linear relationship!  (This happens because any two points on a plane can be connected by a perfect straight line.)

---

> For instance, in linear regression, we have that $Cov(e,\hat Y) = 0$.  That is, the residuals and fitted values are uncorrelated.  Is this always true in any sample realization of residuals and fitted values?

This is actuall a completely different question to the title question.  In the specific case of a regression model using OLS estimation, the residual vector and the fitted response vector *will always be orthogonal*.  This is a stronger property than saying that they have zero covariance in a distributional sense.  It occurs because OLS estimation is equivalent to an [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Alternative_derivations) onto the column space of the design matrix, which decomposes the response vector into a fitted vector and an orthogonal residual vector.

Comment: I generated some random data and got that the covariance between the residuals and fitted values **is** zero after fitting a standard SLR model, so it seems that the population property holds at least sometimes. Is there some criteria for when it holds and when it doesn't?

Comment: In regression, the situation is *stronger* than just having zero covariance at a distributional level.  In that particular situation the residual vector and fitted response vector are orthogonal from the OLS fit.  This is because OLS is equivalent to a projection where the residual and fitted vectors are orthogonal parts of the response (see explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Alternative_derivations)).

Comment: Is this because $Cov(e,\hat Y) = Cov((I-H)Y,HY) = \sigma^2H(I-H) = 0$? I'm having a hard time distinguishing whether this is a distributional property or why it holds for any sample.

Comment: But in the case you offer as a counterexample, the residual $e$ is $0$, and thus has zero covariance with all variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "the residual $e$ is 0"? I see that the elements sum to zero, but not every element is zero

Comment: @Dilip: The title question asks about a general $X$ and $Y$, whereas the body of the question gives a more specific example of a regression residual.  I am answering the title question.

Comment: Ben, OK.  See my own answer which distinguishes between the two different questions.

Comment: @Dilip: I've edited mine to do that too, so as to clearly distinguish the two questions.  Good idea.

Comment: @mikario As Ben pointed out, with two points $X=(x_1,x_2), Y=(y_1,y_2)$, we have that $\hat{Y} = (y_1, y_2)$ and $e = Y - \hat{Y} = (0,0)$ because the two points  determine a straight line which _must_ be the straight line fitted by OLS regression

Answer (score 2):

The question in the title is different from the example provided and has a different answer.

> If $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=0$, is the *sample covariance* between *samples* from $X$ and $Y$ also necessarily zero?

The answer to this is No, the sample covariance need not be zero. The sample covariance is a random variable with *mean* zero and should be expected to have small value (at least compared to $\sigma_X\sigma_Y$), but it is not necessarily *exactly* equal to zero.

> In a linear regression, is the vector $e$ of residuals orthogonal to the vector of estimates?

The answer to this question is Yes.  See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28143/6633) (or the Wikipedia entry cited in a comment by @Ben on his own answer) for a geometric viewpoint as to why this is so.

Comment: [this answer] ?